# Get back total number of rows from Silverlight RIA DomainService, not any other data

Tags: wcf-ria-services

I would like to make continuous calls to the DATABASE to get current row count of a TABLE in every 5 mins. Users using my application are expected to be huge and they will be making calls to DB and I need row count to be able to do some custom stuff.

```
public IQueryable<CPOQC_Errorlog> GetCPOQC_Errorlog()
{
    return this.ObjectContext.CPOQC_Errorlog;
}
```

I do not wish to load all the data from the server as it will put pressure on the server and may result in slow performance. Could there be something like:

```
public int GetCPOQC_Errorlog()
{
    return this.ObjectContext.CPOQC_Errorlog.Count();
}
```

Comment: why dont you try paging in the service side and timer in silverlight to make calls every 1 minute?

Answer (score 0):

you can write a stored procedure which returns only the number of rows from the table and call this stored procedure from service.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a below function in my Domain Service class

```
public int GetCPOQC_ErrorlogCount()
{
    return this.ObjectContext.CPOQC_Errorlog.Count();
}
```

which I invoke from my Silverlight project to get the current row count

```
dataContext.Load(GetCPOQC_ErrorlogCount()).Completed += new EventHandler(errorLogCount_Completed);

void errorLogCount_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int errorLogRowCount = ((InvokeOperation<int>)sender).Value;
}
```